# Problem about normal family

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $D\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a region and $a\in D$. If $F$ is the set of all holomorphisms $f$ on $D$ such that $\mathrm{Re}(f)>0,f(a)=1$,
>
> 1. Prove that $F$ is a normal family on $D$.
> 2. Let $b\in D,b\neq a$. Is the value $\sup_{f\in F}|f(b)|$ bounded?
>      If it's bounded, does there exist a function $g\in F$ satisfying $|g(b)|=\sup_{f\in F}|f(b)|$?
> 3. When there is no condition $f(a)=1$, is $F$ still a normal family? And if the condition  $f(a)=1$ was changed to $|f(a)|\leq 1$, then is $F$ a normal family?

I have no idea at all. Could I use Montel's theorem to deal with this problem?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Yes, Montel and a Möbius transformation.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a nice proof of 1.

Let $$g(z):D(0,1)\rightarrow \{ z\in \mathbb{C}|\Re(z)>0\}$$ be a bioholomorphism such that $g(1)=0$. That exists by Riemman's Theorem.

For every $f\in \mathcal{F}$ the map $g\circ f$ is an holomorphism from $D(0,1)$ on itself, using Schwartz's Lemma we have that for every $z\in D(0,1)$ is $|(g\circ f)(z)|\leq |z|$.

Now let's see that for every closed disk in $D(0,1)$ is $\mathcal{F}$ uniformly bounded. Let $0<r<1$ and $f\in \mathcal{F}$, we now that $|(g\circ f)(z)|\leq |z|\leq r$ in that disk, so turns out $g\circ f$ puts $\bar{D}(0,r)$ into itself, and since $g$ was biholomorphic, in particular $g^{-1} $ is continuos, $$g^{-1}((g\circ f)(\bar{D}(0,r)))\subset g^{-1}(\bar{D}(0,r))=K$$ where $K$ is compact, and since that happens for every $f\in \mathcal{F}$ they're uniformly bounded on every compact in $D(0,1)$, wich means, by Montel's theorem, that the family is normal.